# Firebase- store image files during offline in swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage, offline-mode

I am new to firebase offline storage concept. Firebase is providing service to store data in offline. But, I don't know is they are providing the same for storing files?.

What I exactly want is, I want to store and retrieve image files in firebase when user is in offline.

Please post your answer if anyone knows how to achieve it.

Comment: Do you want to send data after you will be connected internet or WiFi? So you can store your data to CoreData and after you will be connected to Wifi send it to Firebase storage.

Answer (score -1):

This will Old way of firebase API. Current version it wont work:

Firebase Realtime Database client would sync while online persists to disk and is available offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This means your app works as it would online by using the local data stored in the cache.

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

only storing your text content, but i suggest use image to store in the formate of base64EncodedString.

because currently, Storage doesn't offer a similar feature, follow the thread: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/147

To enable offline more info:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: isPersistenceEnabled is only storing your text content.

Comment: yes, my suggestion is to store image in the formate of base64 in database. (base64EncodedString)

Comment: it's not proper way because when they store multiple image at that time application is load more.i would recommend to use NSfileManager to Store your image.

Comment: I'm using file manager right now, it gives me some url like "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F695B76D-C271-4656-8BCD-FF4D4DEF48E0/Documents/fXu8FETgV2b7VAS0by5HyqqbZXD3Dec%2012,%202017%2018:37:33,0.png" and I can load it from local.

Now, how can I store it to the firebase storage once I get connect to internet